# Import file from parent directory?

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following directory structure:

```
application
    tests
        main.py
    main.py
```

application/main.py contains some functions.

tests/main.py will contain my tests for these functions but I can't import the top level main.py. I get the following error:

```
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

I am attempting to import using the following syntax:

```
import main
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd read the documentation first: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Well you can't import the same file name you are working on.

Comment: In which file are you doing `import main` ?

Comment: The fact that a simple task is so complicated in such a supported language is just frustrating. This post has been viewed 141k times and yet some of the answers don't work well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Answer (score 121):

If you'd like your script to be more portable, consider finding the parent directory automatically:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
# import ../db.py
import db
```

Comment: PEP 8: E402 module level import not at top of file

Comment: There is a more serious issue here than the PEP8 one mentioned in the comment above - modifying the sys.path is rarely the solution and more often than not a bad hack - see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/68299898/281545

Answer (score 58):

You must add the application dir to your path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/dir")
from app import object
```

Or from shell:

```
setenv PATH $PATH:"path/to/dir"
```

In case you use windows:
Adding variable to path in [windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Or from the command line:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\dir
```

---

Please mind the diff between `PYTHONPATH`, `PATH`, `sys.path`.

Comment: the only solution to the question title at least

Comment: sys.path and environment variable PATH are two completely different things, they are not equivalent as may your answer suggest. If you do the latter that may work for one machine and not work on the other without the exact same PATH setting. modifying sys.path from inside a python script isn't as intrusive as modifying PATH on the OS or OS user level. Diff between os.path, PythonPATH and PATH: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344841/sys-path-vs-path/64768294#64768294

Answer (score 48):

8 years after - still most other answers here are still not correct unfortunately - apart [LennartRegebro's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16780428/281545) (and BrenBarn's) which is incomplete. For the benefit of future readers - the OP should, first of all, add the `__init__.py` files as in

```
root
    application
        __init__.py
        main.py
        tests
            __init__.py
            main.py
```

then:

```
$ cd root
$ python -m application.tests.main # note no .py
```

or

```
$ cd application
$ python -m tests.main
```

Running a script directly from inside its package is an antipattern - the correct way is running with the [`-m` switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) from the parent directory of the root package - this way all packages are detected and relative/absolute imports work as expected.

Comment: Finally the correct answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Finally I find this answer. A lot of thanks.

Comment: I agree with init.py, but what if you're running from a web hosting environment and not from the terminal?

Comment: @toddmo in that case the environment should be configured to launch the interpreter using the `-m` switch

Comment: Only true working good answer on all the question posts about this. Thank you

Answer (score 27):

First of all you need to make your directories into packages, by adding `__init__.py` files:

```
application
    tests
        __init__.py
        main.py
    __init__.py
    main.py
```

Then you should make sure that the directory above application is on `sys.path`. There are many ways to do that, like making the application infto a package and installing it, or just executing things in the right folder etc.

[Then your imports will work.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: Adding `__init__.py` you make your directories into packages not modules.

Comment: As it is written this allows to import code from subfolders, nor parent folders, and it's not an answer. Though it's helpful anyways.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot import things from parent/sibling directories as such.  You can only import things from directories on the system path, or the current directory, or subdirectories within a package.  Since you have no `__init__.py` files, your files do not form a package, and you can only import them by placing them on the system path.

Comment: Saying without qualification that you cannot is a little strong. You can't do it without a little extra effort, but all you have to do is put the parent directory on the path and you can do it.

Comment: @BryanOakley: That falls under what I said about "placing them on the system path".

Comment: + after going through lot of SOQ I realized that python is blind to look up in parent directories.

Comment: @sakhunzai: This is by design, for code portability.

Answer (score 7):

To import a file in a different subdirectory of the parent directory, try something like this:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../other_sub_dir'))
import filename_without_py_extension
```

Edit: Missing closing bracket.

Answer (score 3):

All answers are slightly confusing for a python newbie like me who isn't making a package and is using pylint. Let me clear it up.

If the directory structure is:

```
application
    main.py
    /tests
        test.py
```

Here is how you import one method from main.py into test.py

Here is `application/main.py`

```
def add_nums(a, b):
    print(a + b)

def subtract_nums(a, b):
    print(a - b)
```

Here is `application/tests/test.py`

```
import sys

sys.path.append("..")
# or sys.path.append("/Users/full/path/to/file")

# pylint: disable=wrong-import-position
from main import add_nums
# pylint: enable=wrong-import-position
```

Comment: Thanks, This is the only solution which worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

in python . exists for same directory, .. for parent directory
to import a file from parent directory you can use ..

> from .. import filename (without .py extension)

Comment: This didn't work for me, `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Comment: This is actually close, but not quite right: you can use `from ..helper import something`, that works with a file `helper.py` in the parent dir.