# sys.path vs. $PATH

Tags: python, bash, filesystems, sys

I would like to access the $PATH variable from inside a python program.  My understanding so far is that sys.path gives the Python module search path, but what I want is $PATH the environment variable.  Is there a way to access that from within Python?

To give a little more background, what I ultimately want to do is find out where a user has Package_X/ installed, so that I can find the absolute path of an html file in Package_X/.  If this is a bad practice or if there is a better way to accomplish this, I would appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "package"? Is it a python module? Or a distribution package for a specific distribution? Depending on what you are looking for, there may already be existing solutions. In the most general case, $PATH is probably not very helpful.

Comment: In `setup.py`, use `data_files` to install external files in a place where your Python package can find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can read environment variables accessing to the `os.environ`dictionary

```
import os

my_path = os.environ['PATH']
```

about searching where a Package is installed, it depends if is installed in PATH

Answer (score 5):

`sys.path` and `PATH` are two entirely different variables. The `PATH` environment variable specifies to your shell (or more precisely, the operating system's `exec()` family of system calls) where to look for binaries, whereas `sys.path` is a Python-internal variable which specifies where Python looks for installable modules.

The environment variable `PYTHONPATH` can be used to influence the value of `sys.path` if you set it before you start Python.

Conversely, `os.environ['PATH']` can be used to examine the value of `PATH` from within Python (or any environment variable, really; just put its name inside the quotes instead of `PATH`).

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893598/pythonpath-vs-sys-path

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a certain module is installed you can simply try importing it:

```
try:
    import someModule
except ImportError, e:
    pass # not installed
```

In order to check its path once its imported you can access its [`__path__`](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories) attribute via `someModule.__path__`:

> Packages support one more special attribute, `__path__`. This is
>   initialized to be a list containing the name of the directory holding
>   the package’s `__init__.py` before the code in that file is executed.

Regarding access to environment variables from within `Python`, you can do the following:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH']
```