# Importing python module from parent folder

Tags: python, path, directory, python-import, python-module

My folder structure is:

```
/mfolder/A/parent.py

/mfolder/A/test/child.py
```

I want to import parent.py file into child.py file. But I'm getting this error

> ImportError: No module named test

(Note: I've set the PYTHONPATH up to /mfolder and have `__init__.py` in test)
How to solve it?? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder) and [import file from parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780014/import-file-from-parent-directory/30536516)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: Please post the traceback and relevant code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import file from parent directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780014/import-file-from-parent-directory)