# ModuleNotFound: No module named 'module_name'

Tags: python

My project structure is the following:

```
.
└── project name
     ├── project name
     │   ├── __init__.py
     │   ├── module.py
     │  
     ├── PACKAGE_A
     │   ├── __init__.py
     │   ├── PACKAGE_A.py
     │   ├── module_a.py
     │
```

In `PACKAGE_A.py`

```py
from module_a import Some_Class

a = Some_Class()

class Another_Class:
    # class code here
```

In `module.py`

```py
"""
Notes
-----
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780014/import-file-from-parent-directory
"""

# Standard library imports
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

# Local application imports
from PACKAGE_A.PACKAGE_A import Another_Class
from PACKAGE_A.module_a import some_function
```

While `module_a.py` and `PACKAGE_A.py` run without problem, running `module.py` fails with:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\project name\project name\module.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PACKAGE_A.PACKAGE_A import Another_Class
  File "path\to\project name\PACKAGE_A\PACKAGE_A.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module_a import Some_Class
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_a'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is a relative import. 

from .module_a import Some_Class (note the dot before module_a)

should do the work. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports

Comment: ```from PACKAGE_A.PACKAGE_A import Another_Class``` fails
```from PACKAGE_A.module_a import some_function``` doesn't fail

Comment: What really fails is the last line of the traceback: `from module_a import Some_Class`. It is called internally when you do `from PACKAGE_A.PACKAGE_A import Another_Class`.

Comment: True. Why does it fail?

Comment: Because you should make a relative import, not absolute one. 

In general, your "`module_a.py` and `PACKAGE_A.py` run without problem" is probably true only when running from `project name/PACKAGE_A` directory.

Comment: Do I need to change the project structure, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your import statement in `PACKAGE_A.py` from:

```
from module_a import Some_Class
```

to:

```
from PACKAGE_A.module_a import Some_Class
```

The reason is that you are adding the `path\to\project name\` to `sys.path`, but you have no `module_a.py` in `path\to\project name\`, and `path\to\project name\PACKAGE_A` (where `module_a.py` resides) is not in `sys.path`.

As for why you succeed in running everything in `PACKAGE_A`, it's because Python adds the directory containing the script you are running to the list (as explained by [gaFF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7814925/gaff)).

I would recommend you read a bit more about python imports, if the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) seems too cluttered, you can check this [link](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html).

This is a personal preference, but I find it simpler to add the root directory of the project to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and then running all the scripts from that directory's level and changing the import statements accordingly. In your example, the root directory would be `path\to\project name\`.

Comment: Alright. I am a bit confused. The above change solved the problem. ```module.py``` does not fail, but now trying to run ```PACKAGE_A.py``` yields```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PACKAGE_A.module_a'; 'PACKAGE_A' is not a package```

Comment: You have to run `PACKAGE_A.py` from the root directory: `cd path\to\project name\`, then `PACKAGE_A/PACKAGE_A.py`. In `PACKAGE_A.py`, import will search for a file `PACKAGE_A/module_a.py` and find it from the current directory.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I mis-explained a part, when I said "current directory" is added to the list, I meant, "The directory containing the file you are running" (My bad), which means, by running `PACKAGE_A.py` Python will start searching the contents of `PACKAGE_A` directory for imports, and not the `project name` directory, which means when you say `PACKAGE_A.module_a`, Python will search for `module_a.py` inside of `PACKAGE_A.py`, which is a file not a directory, thus the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PACKAGE_A.module_a'; 'PACKAGE_A' is not a package`.

Comment: Thanks both of you guys. Would you consider moving all the packages in ```./project name/project name``` folder a better practice? I think this is what @gaFF suggested more or less. Or maybe suggest a "proper" structure for projects?

Comment: Other than taking advantage of `PYTHONPATH`, I would suggest giving packages and the modules they contain different names, having a `PACKAGE_A` that contains a `PACKAGE_A.py` file very confusing, and the more you do it the more confusing it gets. As for the project structure, it would depend on what each module or package is used for as well as personal preference, so I can't really give any advice for this example.

Comment: This is a separate topic. You can find a lot of references on the Web, such as [the hitchhiker guide to Python](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/), [DEV community](https://dev.to/codemouse92/dead-simple-python-project-structure-and-imports-38c6), [Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/), and even on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application).

Answer (score 1):

`import` search for your packages in specific places, listed in `sys.path`. See the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) for the full details.

The current directory is always appended to this list, that's why you succeed to run everything inside `PACKAGE_A`. But from `project name`, there is no way to know where to find `PACKAGE_A`.

Solutions include:

- use relative import
- always run from the root directory (and start all your imports from the root directory)
- add the root directory to the environment variable PYTHONPATH (same)
- use a tool which sets PYTHONPATH when you enter your virtual environment (same)
- ...

and depends on your project and your needs.

Comment: How does ```from PACKAGE_A.PACKAGE_A import Another_Class``` fails while```from PACKAGE_A.module_a import some_function``` doesn't fail, both from ```module.py```?

Comment: From where did you launch `module.py` ? Does `import PACKAGE_A.PACKAGE_A as  PA` works (using `PA.Another_Class` in the code) ? No typo in `Another_Class` ?

Comment: I am launching it from inside its directory (running it from SublimeText, using the build option). The import you mention above, fails with the same ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_a'``` message. No typos. I am using a virtual environment.

Comment: So both `import PACKAGE_A.PACKAGE_A` and `import PACKAGE_A.module_a` fail ? I am not familiar with SublimeText, perhaps search in the option/settings what interpreter is used and from where it is launched.

Comment: No. Only the first import fails.

Comment: Possibly I have to restructure my project