# Python package and module import confusion (using JupyterLab)

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I'm working on a python project in JupyterLab and I'm confused about the package and module import. I get a ModuleNotFoundError (see below) and I don't understand why.

This is my abstracted folder structure:

```
top/
|
|– sub
|   |– __init__.py
|   |– pre.py
|   |– post.py
|   |– sub_main.ipynb
|
|– top_main.ipynb
```

The `__init__.py` is empty.

These are my imports:

`post.py`

```py
from pre import xyz
```

`sub_main.ipynb`

```py
import pre, post
```

`top_main.ipynb`

```py
from sub import pre
```

```py
from sub import post

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pre
```

So, `from sub import pre` is working, but `from sub import post` is not.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!
carlo

Comment: Have you tried restarting the kernel?

Comment: @carloP i suggest you to check this issue that looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120112/module-not-found-during-import-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: @krassowski yes I restarted the kernel multiple times, it doesn't help.

Comment: You need to perform a relative import in `post.py` since you are importing from the same-level module in a package; try `from .pre import xyz`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFound: No module named 'module\_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462283/modulenotfound-no-module-named-module-name)

Comment: @krassowski yes this answers my question! Sorry for the late reply, and thanks very much for your support!