# Unable to Import a file from Parent Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

My file structure is as follows:

```
monitor/
    core/
        database.py
        processor.py
        timekeeper.py
    jobs/
        jobA.py
        jobB.py
    setup.py
```

From `jobA.py` I import like this:

```
from core.database import Database
from core.timekeeper import Timekeeper 
from core.processor import Processor
```

While at `database.py`, `processor.py` and `timekeeper.py` I import `setup.py`.

---

Get the following error when I run `jobA.py`:

```
root@test:/var/www/python/monitor# python3 jobs/jobA.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jobs/jobA.py", line 2, in <module>
    from core.database import Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

Comment: you need to add the path to the parent directory to your python path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780014/import-file-from-parent-directory

Comment: A bit weird hierarchy, why do you create "jobs" in subdirectory if you're planning to execute them directly from shell? Usually there should be launcher script which launch different jobs depending on arguments.

Comment: @OlvinRoght The "jobs" will be executed by cron.

Comment: @Borsn, doesn't matter, actually. Create `launcher.py` which will execute main function from required python script which execute "job" and launch it like you want.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Where should the `launcher.py` be positioned?

Comment: @Borsn in the top directory, ofc.

Comment: @OlvinRoght So have multiple `launcher`'s instead?

Comment: @Borsn, have you erver heard about command line arguments?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Huh?

Comment: @Borsn, `python launcher.py -job1`

Comment: @OlvinRoght Can you please explain a bit more how this works? I'm a newb in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow `import core` or `import core.database` (without the relative dots or double-dots) the parent directory of `core` should either be the current directory, or be included on `sys.path`.   You appear to have a `setup.py`.  Conventionally that means a file that performs installation and packaging tasks via the `setuptools` or `distutils` packages.  If that is indeed the role it performs, perhaps you need to run it.  One way to run it would be to issue (from the command-line outside Python) the command `pip install -e /path/to/monitor`. Assuming `setup.py` was written correctly, this will ensure that the `core` package, in its current location, is lastingly made available for the default Python distribution. Next time you launch Python, `/path/to/monitor` will be on `sys.path` and `import core` will work from (almost) anywhere.

Comment: Wouldn't running `pip install -e /path/to/monitor` build the `monitor` package? So Borsn would have to `from monitor.core import X`? I've only built a few packages so I am genuinely asking, I thought that's how it worked from my experience. Also, thinking about how many packages use `core` or `src` or something to name their directories...

Comment: @MasonCaiby  That actually depends on how `setup.py` is written. Conventionally no, nothing is assumed by default about the location of `setup.py`: the code in `setup.py` must explicitly define which packages (relative to its own location) are being targeted for packaging.  Incidentally, the `-e` flag means that nothing is actually "built", but rather that the parent location of each targeted package is just added to the path (the package is referred to as being "installed as 'editable'")

Comment: If this file structure is of the OP's own design,  is `core` really intended to be a top-level name, importable from anywhere?  If not, and you really mean it to be `monitor.core`, then (a) `setup.py` should be a next to `monitor`, not `core`, and should contain instructions for installing/building the `monitor` package; (b) jobA/jobB should then use relative importing, **but** (c) should they really be there?  With such generic names I imagine they're specific use-cases of the `monitor` package, not reusable submodules.  If so, they should live outside the package and import `monitor.core`.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1054281/225020) answer you can use 2 dots to import from a directory above. So you could potentially use:

```
from .core.database import Database
from .core.timekeeper import Timekeeper 
from .core.processor import Processor
```

Python 3.3+ you don’t need an `__init__.py` file so I don’t believe just adding one will help.

Comment: Error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jobs/jobA.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..core.database import Database
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: My apologies use one dot not 2 I edited the answer.

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me whether OP intends `monitor` to be a top-level package, or just a directory that contains top-level packages.  Two dots **is** correct if `monitor` is supposed to be the top-level package, but it will fail in the manner reported here if the `monitor` package is not accessible (e.g. if the current working directory is `monitor` rather than `monitor`'s parent, and `monitor`'s parent is not in `sys.path`).  Never work inside a directory that you intend to be a package—it causes a lot of confusion.

Comment: You are assuming here that the OP meant for the jobs directory to be a package. It doesn’t appear to have been the case here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters right, and if the jobs directory isn’t a package, it shouldn’t be assuming fixed locations of packages relative to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

to the top of your `jobA.py` file. If you are using python 3.3+, you do not need an `__init__.py` file. It needs to be above your other `import` statements.

Answer (score -2):

What module are you trying to use? Maybe your module is not compatible with Python 3.

Comment: This answer makes more sense if expanded a little bit, to explain that *only* Python 3.3+ will attempt to treat a directory without an `__init__.py` file as a package.